# Posting Event to Page with Latitude and Longitude, and getting a Map Link inserted

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, dictionary, latitude-longitude

My requirement is very simple, and I know that it has been raised before, with no real solution! I have an application that runs automatically every night, and posts several Events to a Facebook Page. That works fine; however I wish to add lat/long values to the events, and have Facebook then display a mini-map accurately based on those lat/long values. I know that if I manually edit the posts, Facebook will attempt a geocode from the address, and display the mini-map, but that is of no use.

Facbook Page Home:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/DanceWeb/316030661254